# How to regenerate CouchBD data from ledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using fabric 1.1 Alfa and running a 3 Organizations network in a single channel. My three Organizations are Manufacturer, Transporter and Retailer with 1 peer each. I can go to any of my couch Db node and modify any key-value pair eg (I change value of amount) but what I do not get here is how would I know which org has the corrupted or modified data? or who did that? Because on the client side we show the state data only, which is modifiable.

is there any way i can repopulate couchDB data from ledger or get to know who tried to corrupt the data?

Answer (score 0):

One (indirect) way to do this, would be to join a new peer to the network with his own couchdb attached. When new blocks are gossiped to this new peer, the peer automatically updates the couchdb until he receives the latest block. Then you can have a look at the couchdb world state which will be the "correct" state.

Comment: I am relevantly very new to this. I see when I change the state of a key from couchDB and transfer it to other Org, only the latest tampered data is showed in next org so in this situation how is the block chain important? how to catch which org was culprit and tried to corrupt data?